# Passing a Parameter from DataGrid to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, gridview

I have a aspx webpage that is using webforms.  I have a gridview that has a series of buttons in each row.  For one button I would like to show a Jquery popup that makes the user either confirm or cancel their request.  I have the popup working.  I can send data to the webpage's code behind.  But my issue is passing the data about that particular entry to the javascript function.

This is my function I want to run

```
    function confirmDelete(MarketerNumber) {
        alert(MarketerNumber);
        $("#dialog-confirmDelete").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 200,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Disable Marketer": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    DisableMarketer();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

However this line is cauisng me an issue

```
<asp:Button ID="lnkDisable" runat="server" CausesValidation ="False" Text="Disable" CssClass="miniButtonWidth125" OnClientClick="confirmDelete('<%# Bind('ID') %>'); return false" />
```

Any idea why this doesn't work